# Reactjs : Getting active element name from <ul> in to the header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I am trying to build a long navbar for mobile device and I am developing it in an accordion style. The first view will have currently active link name. The user when clicks on this active link name, it expands below and list out other available links.

```
React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          tab: false,
          navState: "nav-closed"
        }
      },
      handleClick: function() {
        if (this.state.tab) {
          this.setState({
            tab: false,
            navState: "nav-closed"
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            tab: true,
            navState: "nav-open"
          })
        }
      },
      render: function() {
        return (<div>
        <div className ="navbar-container">
        <div onClick = {this.handleClick}>HEADER` 
          /*  (should display active element name here) */
        </div>
        <div className = {this.state.navState}>
        <ul role="nav">
              <li onClick = {this.handleClick}><Link activeClassName="active" to="path1">PATH 1</Link></li>
              <li onClick = {this.handleClick}><Link activeClassName="active" to="/path2">PATH 2</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
            {this.props.children}
      </div>)
      }
    })
```

In the code sample, I am trying to get the currently active link (PATH1 or PATH2) in place of "HEADER"

Any suggestions or advice what I should be looking in to?

Answer (score 2):

You can get text of the clicked link by accessing `currentTarget.interHtml` property of the event object passed as the argument to `handleClick` method:

```
handleClick: function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.innerHTML); // should log PATH 1 or PATH 2
  //...
}
```

So I could advice something like:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      heder: '',
      tab: false,
      navState: "nav-closed"
    }
  },
  handleClick: function(e) {
    let header = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    if (this.state.tab) {
      this.setState({
        tab: false,
        navState: "nav-closed",
        header
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        tab: true,
        navState: "nav-open",
        header
      })
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div>
    <div className ="navbar-container">
    <div onClick = {this.handleClick}>{this.state.header}
    </div>
    <div className = {this.state.navState}>
    <ul role="nav">
          <li onClick = {this.handleClick}><Link activeClassName="active" to="path1">PATH 1</Link></li>
          <li onClick = {this.handleClick}><Link activeClassName="active" to="/path2">PATH 2</Link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
        {this.props.children}
  </div>)
  }
})
```

Comment: Would that be a clean way to do this? because handle click is also called when there is a click on header too.. also on a toggle icon in future..

Comment: I've understood that you need to copy link contents to the header, since you've hardcoded `PATH 1` and `PATH 2`. If it's not the case than take a look at the suggestion provided by @Yury. Might be cleaner way. Or you can separate handlers for different links.

Comment: I tried Jquery(".navigation-bar li > .active").text() and it works... but when we renter the url, the text remains the same instead of reseting to initial value.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use dom manipulation via jquery in react apps.

Comment: ok.. I thought since we were using let header = e.currentTarget.innerHTML, using let header =Jquery(".navigation-bar li > .active").text(); wont do any harm

Comment: i was trying to get the default active element, but this way we only get it on click.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Consider adding caption argument to click handler.

```
React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          tab: false,
          navState: "nav-closed",
          caption: ''
        }
      },
      handleClick: function(caption) {
        if (this.state.tab) {
          this.setState({
            tab: false,
            navState: "nav-closed",
            caption
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            tab: true,
            navState: "nav-open",
            caption
          })
        }
      },
      render: function() {
        return (<div>
        <div className ="navbar-container">
        <div onClick ={() => this.handleClick(this.state.caption)}>{this.state.caption}
        </div>
        <div className = {this.state.navState}>
        <ul role="nav">
              <li onClick = {() => this.handleClick('PATH 1')}><Link activeClassName="active" to="path1">PATH 1</Link></li>
              <li onClick = {() => this.handleClick('PATH 2')}><Link activeClassName="active" to="/path2">PATH 2</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
            {this.props.children}
      </div>)
      }
    })
```

Or better add `links` array to component state and generate all links based on its values.

```
 <ul role="nav">
    {this.state.links.map(link => (
      <li key={link.to} onClick={() => this.handleClick(link.caption)}>
          <Link ... to={link.to} >{link.caption}</Link>
      </li>
    ))}
 </ul>
```

Comment: I ve been playing around with this. Since there is an ajax request attached to this component, inside this.setState will cause recursion error.

Answer (score -1):

You handle de click to a target on event, before toggle the class (or attributes) of element. 
Check this example.

```js
const NavBar = React.createClass({
  handleClick(e){
    let nav = document.querySelectorAll('#nav li')
    Array.from(nav).map(list =>{
      list.classList.toggle('active', false)
    })
    e.target.classList.toggle('active', true)
    
    let getActiveLink = document.querySelector('.active')
    console.log(getActiveLink.innerText)
  },
  render(){
    return(<ul id='nav'>
             <li onClick={ this.handleClick }>Link one</li>
             <li onClick={ this.handleClick }>Link two</li>
             <li onClick={ this.handleClick }>Link tree</li>
           </ul>)
  }
})
   
ReactDOM.render(<NavBar/>, document.getElementById('foo'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='foo'><div>
```

Comment: Why would OP need to manually change DOM? The whole point of react virtual dom is that user do not change dom manually.

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko The guy wants to take the text within the 'active' link, this is a dynamic example.

Comment: I think that @YuryTarabanko meant this part: `list.classList.toggle('active', false)` is a bad practice. It's not a React way.

Comment: @RuiCosta Not really. OP wants do display some data that due to current implementation only available in DOM. No reason to make things even worse.